# How to deny access to my server end points?

Tags: php, access-control, node.js

How do I restrict access to a React Web app installed at `www.example.com`, in particular the (Node JS or PHP) backend server REST API endpoints? I want to only allow access to the pages and backend from a specific office IP address.

I tried

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com');
```

but it doesn't block the end points when I try to access them from another IP.

Maybe instead I have to check the client IP within the endpoint code and deny access if the IP doesn't match, but what if the IP is dynamic?

PS I'm using JWT to secure the endpoints (authentication) and HTTPS.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me... People visit www.example.com. This will make requests to your webserver, both for static files (HTML), and your PHP endpoints (the user clicks some button specified by said HTML). Who exactly do you want to block? Do you only want to allow people from your office to visit your site?

Comment: @marcelm yes, I want it to be hosted on my clients server for convenience and to use a database on the server, but only allow use by the office IP address. I solved this by setting up a '.htaccess' file in the root '/projects/' folder which contains all the PHP and HTML files. I wanted to protect the end points in particular. From the accepted answer I was able to discern this solution. It's very simple and works. Occam's Razor for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I solved the problem:

In your server's File Manager, in the folder you wish to restrict access, create a new `.htaccess` file and add the following lines:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address you wish to allow.

You can grant additional access by comma separating IP addresses or if that doesn't work just use additional `Allow from` lines.

I believe you can also add wildcard IP addresses too.

Answer (score 5):

First, regarding what you have tried already:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com');`

This will fail for a number of reasons:

1. This a client-level control that doesn't stop anyone from making requests to your endpoint anyway.  This is, in fact, a flag for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in a browser, and isn't actually relevant to your use case.  It would not have any impact at all with your current setup, nor would it even necessarily stop people from accessing your API endpoints even if they were on another domain (`CORS` is a read restriction, not a write restriction).
2. As you allude to, even if this worked as intended, it would not actually do what you want, since it would stop people from using your endpoint from within a browser on a different domain, but that would not actually lock it down to your office at all
3. It also wouldn't work anyway because regardless of what headers you pass back any non-browser client can ignore your headers and just do what they want.  I.e. a browser will listen to `CORS` restrictions (because that is how browsers work) but I can hit up any endpoint I want with `curl`, `postman`, or any other http client and do whatever I want anyway.  It's not just browsers that use the internet, so you can't make any assumptions about who is browsing your site how.

**IP Filtering**

In a case like this the best bet is to simply filter by ip address, which you mentioned.  Generally offices have static IP addresses or change rarely, so it is actually quite feasible to do.  Presuming the entire office is NATed behind one router/ip address then it is quite simple because you just need the one rule: dump all traffic except port 80 (443?) coming from the office IP.  You probably shouldn't bother doing this with PHP, however, because for PHP to reject the request on the basis of the IP address first requires your server to process the request, launch PHP, and pass it along.  A simple firewall rule is much easier on server resources.  Dynamic office IP addresses are almost unheard of, so unless you know that that is the situation for you, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you. I had my reservations about Access-Control, as I'd read it was not designed to restrict access, or something like that. I will give IP filtering a go from behing the firewall. Ideally I would need to filter only a portion of the domain, e.g. `https://www.example.com/projects/`

Comment: I may be able to achieve this by creating a .htaccess file in my `/projects/` server folder (possibly)

Comment: You probably can, and it will get you slightly performance than with PHP, although not necessarily as much as you think. Apache loads up the PHP interpreter for every request, so your footprint is still large. However, that isn't me saying that is a bad idea. For small applications server resources are rarely a problem, so using .htaccess or even PHP are unlikely to cause you actual problems.

Comment: resources aren't really a problem, but this is something to bear in mind for future work.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea on the domains is rather wrong. You need to understand one essential thing about a web server.

There is no such thing like "an access from a domain". It is not a "software" which is sending requests to endpoints but *a client* (which is usually a browser). A client *may* read some information from your server first, but it's unnecessary.

Long story short, you cannot limit an access to your endpoints "from a domain".

The idea for the ip address is more fruitful, and more plausible than you think. Offices seldom change their IP, least they use a dynamical one. So you can limit access to the whole www.example.com server (not only endpoints) based on the IP address of your office.

Though there is another culprit, as IP address can be *forged*, and thus it is possible to create a request that will be allowed to send something to your endpoint (however without the ability to get the response).

But I would consider such a protection rather unnecessary given you are using JWT for the authentication (and, I assume, HTTPS for the secured connection).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I knew my understanding of the basic principles was incorrect. I am using SSL/TLS for communication and JWT for authentication, but my client is requesting I block access from outside their IP.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be setting up TLS **client** certificates.

It requires you to create your own certificate authority (CA) and issue client certificates to your end-users. Ideally, you should issue separate certificates for each client device, but it is possible to use just a single shared certificate (with a security tradeoff).

Then, on your server you just tell **Apache** to require the client to present a valid certificate issued by your own CA:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/client-auth-ca.crt
```

or, **nginx**:

```
ssl_client_certificate /path/to/client-auth-ca.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

Anyone who is unable to present a valid client certificate issued by your CA will get `401 Authorization Required`.

**Pros**:

- Great UX - almost no interaction required for end users, especially in browsers. They just type the URL and **it works™** (provided everything has been set up correctly).
- Your visitors are not restricted to the pre-defined set of IPs, support for road warriors
- Very secure - provided you secure the certificates so they cannot be easily extracted (ideally, one should generate and keep them on smartcards). It may be possible to brute-force or guess the password, but almost impossible to brute-force 4096-bit RSA key, so here only key theft (or device theft) is a real threat.
- Can be used to distinguish between users
- Can protect the whole webserver, both PHP endpoints and static files.

**Cons**:

- not very common, may be unfamiliar to users
- require some more effort to set up (compared to enabling IP whitelists)
- some software that does not support client certificates (not browsers) may be unable to access the endpoints